# Masked EditText is not working android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

i want to use Masked EditText for edit text cart number but my code is error and i do not understand whats problem
please help me

my error:

`Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #142: Binary XML file line #142: Error inflating class com.example.maskedlib.MaskedEditText
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #142: Error inflating class com.example.maskedlib.MaskedEditText`

my code xml:

```
<com.example.maskedlib.MaskedEditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_cart_number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-2dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ibutton_mic"
            android:background="@null"
            app:mask="####-####-####-####"
            android:fontFamily="@font/iswebmedium"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:hint="@string/txt_cart"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColorHint="@color/color_input_cart"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

there is 2 nice tutorial on these link :

https://github.com/egslava/edittext-mask

https://medium.com/@diegoy_kuri/masks-in-android-edit-text-fields-33a2fd47f1af

You have to create a class for the mask because the attribute "app:mask" dont work like this (like android:fontFamily sometimes).

Hope these tuto will help you !